# How do I preload images from an array of urls in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a music app that I want to preload album arts for. Right now, when you hit next song it loads the album art from a URL but it would be nice if it was already preloaded and in memory. I've tried a few things but nothing seems to really work. Does anyone know of a technique that where I can preload images in iOS and then look for that image later and if its not there, then download it?

**Edit with some more detail...**

When I go to play a 'station' on my app, I make a request to a server that returns JSON for the playlist. Inside of this JSON is each song as well as data including the album art URL. When a user goes to play a 'station' I would like to preload images for either the next album art URL in the stack or all album art URLs in the entire playlist.

Anyways, I've tried loading the next album art URL in a UIImage in the background as like a `temporaryAlbumArt` and then when the next song is played simply do `albumArt = temporaryAlbumArt` and then repeat the process setting the next songs album art to temp and so on..

I've tried something like this:

```
if (temporaryAlbumArt) {
  albumArt = temporaryAlbumArt
} else {
  albumArt = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:firstAlbumArtURL]]];
}

temporaryAlbumArt = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nextAlbumArtURL]]];
```

I guess my question is, what is the best method of:

- loading an image or multiple images from a URL(s) into memory
- using those images later on without any lag time

Comment: Be more specific. What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I agree, what part of this are you struggling with specifically? Algorithm? Code? Some clarification will help us help you! ;)

Comment: I've made some updates, I'm not sure if they're helpful though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library does what you need: [JMImageCache](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache)

Loop through your URLs, download them through JMImageCache and when you need to show an image the library will fetch the stored image if it's finished downloading.

```
//You can do this when you get the array of urls to download the images in the background
for(NSURL *url in urls) {
    [[JMImageCache sharedCache] imageForURL:url];
}

//and then when you need an image:
[imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: This is **exactly** what I've been trying to do except I've been getting `No visible @interface for 'JMImageCache' declares the selector 'imageForURL'` - it forces me to pass in all parameters including the `completionBlock` and `failureBlock`. Not sure why I can't just load an image into the cache without doing anything with it immediately.

Comment: I wrote that by memory, if it needs completion/failure block you can just pass nil to those. Or use blocks to keep track of how many images have finished downloading or failed (so that you can show a progress indicator).

Comment: So, I've gotten this to work, slightly, but for some reason it freezes up the app and clogs up the main queue. It's supposed to run in the background and even when I dispatch it in the background, still happens.

Comment: It does use GCD to run in the background so it should be ok. Something else must be the problem. Maybe you should add a new question or edit this one to post some of the code if you can't find what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this "must have" tool [APSmartStorage](https://github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage). It supports everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not for sure what you are asking but if you know what the next song is going to be couldn't you just down load it in a background thread then have it ready for display when the next song starts?

If you want the app to store all the downloaded images locally you may eventually run into space issues but its do able. You could use the downloaded image then store it in the caches directory (not document dir or Apple will get mad!). When a song comes just do a quick check for the image and if its not local download it. Songs take a few minutes so there should be time to do all this in the background.

```
#define GET_QUEUE dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

// while song is playing...
dispatch_async(GET_QUEUE, ^{
  // On a separate thread look for the image locally in the cache and then
  // download it if necessary
});
```

I'm not sure if this answers your question or not...

Ok so here is a bit more code - basically it lets me ask hopefully helpful questions in context.

```
// Inside some loop/method that plays songs...
if (temporaryAlbumArt)
  albumArt = temporaryAlbumArt
else
  albumArt = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:firstAlbumArtURL]]]; 
  // If this keeps executing then perhaps temporaryAlbumArt is getting released somehow?
  // Are you persisting it correctly through each iteration/method call?

// show art...
// start music    

// Call art update
dispatch_async(GET_QUEUE, ^{
  temporaryAlbumArt = nil; // In case the data hasn't been obtained yet on the next iteration???
  temporaryAlbumArt = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nextAlbumArtURL]]]; 
  // This works ok then? Can you make sure this is completing correctly before the next iteration/method call?
});
```

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Precisely what I've been trying to do but I'm wondering what the best method of loading the image in the background is and then using that same image when the next track is called for. When I do something like this: `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]]];` and then use that same UIImage for the next song, it doesn't seem to work. It goes and loads the image all over again.

Comment: Hmm, well I guess we need some more code to look at... Sounds like you are calling the method when you shouldn't be. I'll update my answer with a bit more info but then I'm off to bed for the night! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, no worries. I added some more detail of what I've tried in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code to download data from server and save that data into document directory so that next time if anybody hit the same url,it is fetched from document directory without any server hit.

```
-(void)downloadImageForProductsFromArray:(NSArray *)inventoryArr {
BOOL isAllDataDownloaded = YES;
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.labelText = @"Data Sync...";
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"operations" options:0 context:nil];
for (int i = 0; i < inventoryArr.count; i++) {
    NSString *productUrlStr = [inventoryArr objectAtIndex:i];
    NSData *dirData = [CommonUtils fetchImageDataFromDirectoryWithImageName: productUrlStr];/*****Check whether Image data is already downloaded and saved in document directory*****/
    if (!dirData) {
        isAllDataDownloaded = NO;

        NSBlockOperation *downloadImgOpr = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
        downloadImgOpr.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryHigh;
        downloadImgOpr.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUserInitiated;

        [downloadImgOpr addExecutionBlock:^{
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: productUrlStr]];
            if (imageData) {

                /*****Save Image Data in Document Directory*****/
            }
        }];

    } 
}
if (isAllDataDownloaded) {
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
}}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                     change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
if (object == [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"operations"]) {
    if ([[NSOperationQueue mainQueue].operations count] == 0) {
        // Do something here when your queue has completed
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];

        NSLog(@"queue has completed");
    }
}
else {
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
                           change:change context:context];
}
```

}

In This code i have all the url strings in the inventory array.In for loop i have made several operations and added those operations into the queue(**I have used main queue for holding UI and syncing data.Choose your queue appropriately**).Also I have added the KVO to the queue for keypath value "operations" so that if count of operations is 0,we can do the useful operation.